# ngFor solution for 4 different variations

Tags: angular, ngfor

I have 4 buttons that are split in pairs (A1,A2 and B1,B2).

I also have 4 different paragraphs that i want to show based on variations of checked buttons ...4 variation should be A1B1, A1B2, A2B1 and A2B2 ...

I managed to make [plunker](https://stackblitz.com/edit/ngfor-example-5g7gut) to show some basic principle, but still haven't founded solution on how can I make ngFor to load only one matching paragraph to button combination so then, if I click button A1 and button B2, it will show me only paragraph for that code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use *ngIf and have a method to update selection when anything is changed, I think this is what you're looking for ,

```js
changeA( aValue ) {
        this.currentA = aValue;
        this.aElem = this.currentA;
        this.selectedMonthElem = this.currentA;
        this.setSelection();
        
    }
    
changeB( bValue ) {
        this.currentB = bValue;
        this.bElem = this.currentB;
        this.selectedYearElem = this.currentB;
        this.setSelection();
    }

setSelection() {
    this.selection = this.currentA + this.currentB;
}
```

```html
<button #elem1 value="A1" (click)="changeA(elem1.value)">A1</button>
<button #elem2 value="A2" (click)="changeA(elem2.value)">A2</button>
<button #elem3 value="B1" (click)="changeB(elem3.value)">B1</button>
<button #elem4 value="B2" (click)="changeB(elem4.value)">B2</button>

<p *ngIf="selection == 'A1B1'">Paragraph For A1B1</p>
<p *ngIf="selection == 'A1B2'">Paragraph For A1B2</p>
<p *ngIf="selection == 'A2B1'">Paragraph For A2B1</p>
<p *ngIf="selection == 'A2B2'">Paragraph For A2B2</p>
```

You can still have the paragraph content inside an object and make the whole structure like a map. that way we don't need to use multiple *ngIf and hardcodings.. let me know if you prefer that solution

Updated working code : https://stackblitz.com/edit/ngfor-example-ntnm1x

Comment: Thanks... I misplaced ngFor and ngIf ... multiple ngIfs are fine for me because i use more different and complex items instead of paragraphs